# Dispaly total number of requests made in a stipulated time interval

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

In Grafana, would like to display the number of requests made in a period of selected time interval(by selecting the time interval in top right corner), let it be `1m` or `15m` or `3h` or `24h` or `7d` or `1y`.

[image]
[image]

Prometheus is my data source and below is the query. My question being, how can I pass the time interval dynamically in the prom query tab of Grafana, instead of passing `24h`or any fixed integer per se.

```
django_api_calls_total - django_api_calls_total offset 24h > 0
```

[image]

Comment: you can use the built-in variable that provided by grafana which allows you to control time range dynamically   django_api_calls_total - django_api_calls_total offset $__interval > 0

Comment: @HasanRaza : Can you please explain a bit or may be share a screenshot from Grafana if possible ? I don't have much idea about `built-in variable`

Comment: @HasanRaza : It throws - `Error executing query: 1:56: parse error: unexpected character: '$'` if I execute -`django_api_calls_total - django_api_calls_total offset $__interval > 0`

Comment: django_api_calls_total - django_api_calls_total offset $__range > 0 use this

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/  you can get more guidance from here

Comment: so sorry $__interval is not a built-in variable

Comment: Thanks @HasanRaza . it gives me negative values if I select a time range of 6 hours with the above mentioned query.

Comment: Use `increase(django_api_calls_total[$__range])`. It will adjust for counter resets automatically, but might produce noninteger results. If you insist on integer values use either `round` or some clever logic of mixing increase and affect approaches.